# refactor a function having multiple else if blocks

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following function where I set points for date based on their months. But I am hard coding the values. I want to re factor the function and remove the redundant else if block. As we can see when the days is decreased by a certain value, n-1 points are deducted. So, how can I refactor it?

```js
points = {}

function calcPointsForDates(createdTime) {

  let today = new Date()
  let Y = today.getFullYear()
  let M = today.getMonth()
  let T = today.getDate()

  let monthAgo = days => new Date(Y, M, T - days).getTime()

  if (createdTime > monthAgo(30)) {
    points.date = 2
  } else if (createdTime < monthAgo(180)) {
    points.date = -5
  } else if (createdTime < monthAgo(90)) {
    points.date = -4
  } else if (createdTime < monthAgo(60)) {
    points.date = -3
  } else if (createdTime < monthAgo(30)) {
    points.date = -2
  }
}
calcPointsForDates(post.created.getTime())
```

Comment: what do you think `createdTime > monthAgo(30) && monthAgo(90)` means? looks out of place ... `&& monthAgo(90)` may as well have `&& true`

Comment: I don't think there's any refactoring that will make sense - i.e. you could do some fancy maths setting the value using some formula - but, will that be readable?

Comment: If it were always the same comparison, you could put all the time periods in an array. Then loop through the array until the condition matches, and use the array index to set `points.date`. But it doesn't seem like there's a consistent way to do that.

Comment: Your first `if` is a bit strange. First of all, it should probably be `if createdTime > monthAgo(30) && createdTime > monthAgo(90)`.  But also, the second condition is not needed at all. Because every timestamp that is `> monthAgo(30)` is obviously also `> monthAgo(90)`.

Comment: seriously, the code works, it's readable therefore maintainable, just leave running code alone :p

Comment: sorry for the confusion, guys. "&& monthAgo(90)"  is not required in the first IF block

Answer (score 1):

Consider a points object with properties that are the break values for points that can be used to implement the same logic as your if..else blocks, e.g.

```
let days2points = {'30': 2, '60': -2, '90': -3, '180': -4, '1e10': -5};
```

The value is found by looping over the keys to find the first where the number of days (*diff*) is less than the key. That is then used to return the value so where *diff* < 30 return 2, where *diff* < 60 return -2, etc.
The value '1e10' essentially represents infinity, it might be set to Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER (9007199254740991 days or about 24.6 trillion years ago).

So get the difference in days between today and the *createdDate*, find the relevant key and return the points, e.g.

```js
function getPoints(createdTime) {
  // Create a points object for points related to days ago
  let days2points = {'30': 2, '60': -2, '90': -3, '180': -4, '1e10': -5}; 

  // Get the number of days between today and createdTime
  let diff = (new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) - createdTime) / 8.64e7;

  // Find the relevant value in the points object
  let key = Object.keys(days2points).find(daysAgo => diff < daysAgo);

  // Debug
  console.log('Days ago: ' + diff + ' Value: ' + days2points[key]);

  // Return the value
  return days2points[key];
} 

// Examples
let d = new Date();
let [Y, M, D] = [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()];
[ d,                        // today
  new Date(Y, M, D -   3),  //   3 days ago
  new Date(Y, M, D -  30),  //  30 days ago
  new Date(Y, M, D -  33),  //  33 days ago
  new Date(Y, M, D -  63),  //  63 days ago
  new Date(Y, M, D -  93),  //  93 days ago
  new Date(Y, M, D - 183)   // 183 days ago
].forEach(d => 
  console.log(d.toDateString() + ' => ' + getPoints(d))
);
```

The above uses `<` for comparison, so that the break points are not inclusive and 30 days ago returns -2. If they should be inclusive, make the comparison `<=` or add 1 to the break points.

**Caveats**

The method of calculating *diff* is approximate, there are better ways.

Object properties from *Object.keys* are not required to be in the same order as the object literal used to create *days2points*, so strictly they should be ordered before iterating over them.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your limits and datepoints to an array and iterate that array from lowest to highest. If a condition for a limit is met, return the respective datepoints. If none is met, return the default value.

```js
const 
  datePoints = [
      [180, -5],
      [90, -4],
      [60, -3],
      [30, -2]
    ],
  defaultPoints = 2;

function daysAgo(d) {
  const now = new Date();
  return new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay() - d);
}

function getDatePoints(createdTime) {
  for (let d of datePoints) {
    if (createdTime < daysAgo(d[0]))
      return d[1];
  }
      
  return defaultPoints;
}

for (let i = 1; i < 200; i+= 10)
  console.log(i, daysAgo(i).toISOString(), getDatePoints(daysAgo(i)));
```